# Exoplayer media3 keeps displaying embedded artwork instead of metadata artwork in my music player - how can I fix this?

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3

I am making a music player using Media3 ExoPlayer with Compose (Material 3). I am setting the metadata artwork uri, but once the song starts playing, it shows my artwork for a second but then quickly replaced by the embedded artwork.

I am using the default notification media3 generates. I was hoping if there was any way to disable the load embedded artwork feature.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem and fixed by adding `setBitmapLoader` to `MediaSession.Builder` like this:

```
mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, player)
            .setBitmapLoader(object : BitmapLoader{
            override fun decodeBitmap(data: ByteArray): ListenableFuture<Bitmap> {
                return  Futures.immediateFuture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.notification_large_icon))
            }

            override fun loadBitmap(
                uri: Uri,
                options: BitmapFactory.Options?
            ): ListenableFuture<Bitmap> {
                return  Futures.immediateFuture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.notification_large_icon))
            }
        })
        .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that wrapping your bitmap loader with CacheBitmapLoader will cause this issue.

The method to override in BitmapLoader is loadBitmapFromMetadata(). The default implementation is:

```
  default ListenableFuture<Bitmap> loadBitmapFromMetadata(MediaMetadata metadata) {
@Nullable ListenableFuture<Bitmap> future;
if (metadata.artworkData != null) {
  future = decodeBitmap(metadata.artworkData);
} else if (metadata.artworkUri != null) {
  future = loadBitmap(metadata.artworkUri);
} else {
  future = null;
}
return future;
```

}

which will call decodeBitmap() on the embedded artwork first, before calling loadBitmap().

If you need to ignore embedded artwork altogether, you can override that method:

```
override fun loadBitmapFromMetadata(metadata: MediaMetadata): ListenableFuture<Bitmap> {
        return loadBitmap(metadata.artworkUri!!)
    }
```